# Using swing how do I dim an unfocused text field?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

A user is allowed to choose only one option from a few. Each option is represented by a text field (user is required to put some text there) so I though it should be nice to dim a field which is unfocused to let user understand he may choose one option.

[image]

Can anyone please advise me with an example / link to one for something similar?

Comment: What about adding radio buttons, one for each field, and disabling the unselected one?

Comment: @whiskeyspider good idea, I don't like the way it looks though.

Comment: `setEnabled`?  Based on you current design, that might also suggest a need for a `DocumentListener`, so you can make decisions about which field to dim and when

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the basic idea would be to simple use `setEnabled` to change the enabled state of the field which you don't want modified.  The difficult part is knowing when to to disable/enable the fields

Fortunately, the `JTextField`'s `Document` can generate events when it's updated.  See [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details

So, with this in hand, we can do something like this...

```
public class ManagedDocumentHandler implements DocumentListener {

    private JTextField toBe;
    private JTextField orNotToBe;

    public ManagedDocumentHandler(JTextField toBe, JTextField orNotToBe) {
        this.toBe = toBe;
        this.orNotToBe = orNotToBe;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateState();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateState();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateState();
    }

    protected void updateState() {
        toBe.setEnabled(true);
        orNotToBe.setEnabled(toBe.getText().trim().length() == 0);
    }

}
```

Knowing that we have two fields, one will be enabled when the contents is changed, the other will (likely) be disabled when the other is changed (except if the field is empty, then they are both enabled)

[image: YouShellNotPass]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class MakeItSo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MakeItSo();
    }

    public MakeItSo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            add(new JLabel("Choose this:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JLabel("Or this:"), gbc);

            JTextField thisOne = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField orThisOne = new JTextField(10);

            thisOne.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new ManagedDocumentHandler(thisOne, orThisOne));
            orThisOne.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new ManagedDocumentHandler(orThisOne, thisOne));

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;

            add(thisOne, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(orThisOne, gbc);
        }

        public class ManagedDocumentHandler implements DocumentListener {

            private JTextField toBe;
            private JTextField orNotToBe;

            public ManagedDocumentHandler(JTextField toBe, JTextField orNotToBe) {
                this.toBe = toBe;
                this.orNotToBe = orNotToBe;
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateState();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateState();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateState();
            }

            protected void updateState() {
                toBe.setEnabled(true);
                orNotToBe.setEnabled(toBe.getText().trim().length() == 0);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: My disabled text field does not change its color though. I use different layout but it not seems to be related to it.

Comment: The layout manager is unlikely to be the cause, either the look and feel your using doesn't change the color or you're referencing the wrong fields

Comment: which one do you use in your example? Trying to avoid spending too much time on finding out which one will work. Thanks!

Comment: The "system" look and feel (windows in the example)